# Log long-running queries against a MySQL database?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, tomcat

We have a web application (Tomcat/Spring/Hibernate) running against a MySQL database.   Every once in a while, the application runs a data-driven query that takes a huge amount of time to complete.   Right now, we have no way to track them without logging ALL the queries, which would be a huge number (very busy app.)  The only way we can identify a query is if it actually times out, then we get a `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool abandon` warning.

Is there some way in Tomcat, Spring or Hibernate to track only queries that take over a certain time to execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has a slow query log. Enable that if it isn't already.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html

Comment: I'm marking this answer correct because it actually gives me what I needed to solve this problem.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Session factory has getStatistics() method to know all kinds of statistics. Find about it [here](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19807.html). You may be interested in `stats.getQueryExecutionMaxTime()` method.